# Appending a dataframe to dictionary of dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary structured with all the results of a test_train_split run 50 times. However, from time to time I need to force an already removed subset into the testing dataframes. Currently I'm using `while sel < 5:
sel += 1

```
count = 0
while count < 50:
    count += 1
    #Running a loop to get the samples
    num_samples = 100
    
    #creating empty dictionaries
    test_dict = dict()        # This dictionary will have contain all the test dataframes
    ctrl_dict = dict()        # This dictionary will have contain all the control dataframes
    
    if io == 1:  
        try:
                for x in range(num_samples):
                    test_dict[x] , ctrl_dict[x] = train_test_split(data, test_size = 1-patchPct , stratify=data[['sales_per_store_rank', 'store_cnt_rank', 'division']])
        except:
                for x in range(num_samples):
                    test_dict[x] , ctrl_dict[x] = train_test_split(data, test_size = 1-patchPct , stratify=data[['sales_per_store_rank', 'store_cnt_rank']])
    elif io == 2:
        try:
                for x in range(num_samples):
                    test_dict[x] , ctrl_dict[x] = train_test_split(data, test_size = 1-patchPct , stratify=data[['sales_per_store_rank', 'store_cnt_rank', 'division']])
                    test_dict.update
        except:
                for x in range(num_samples):
                    test_dict[x] , ctrl_dict[x] = train_test_split(data, test_size = 1-patchPct , stratify=data[['sales_per_store_rank', 'store_cnt_rank']])
                    for x in test_dict:
                        x|patchdataincl`
```

Where when io == 2 then it should append that dataframe onto all of the testing dataframes in the dictionary... I've tried df.update, and merge.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: `test_dict = dict()` is _inside_ your `while` loop, so it just gets completely wiped on every iteration. "`# This dictionary will have contain all the test dataframes`" no, it'll contain, at most, 1 dataframe. You need to move this and `ctrl_dict = dict()` above the `while` loop (I haven't reviewed the rest but that should help start)

Comment: There are some other serious problems with this code as well - relying on `try .. except` to decide between cases is an anti-pattern, since you can probably tell from some other attribute on the DataFrame whether or not it will fail. And if you explain what you're really aiming to do, I'm pretty sure Pandas has some built-in feature that does all this for you already and the juggling of data in dictionaries won't even be needed. This looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I had inherited this code and still kind of fumbling through it. But @roganjosh got me thinking and was correct. I didn't need to move the test_dict outside of the loop. It was all being handled later in the code. But I did need t move the append to later in the code and not within the try...except as Grismar had noted. Thanks for getting the juices flowing.

Comment: After a few more convrosations. Solution was due two part. inside the wrong loop and also it wasn't appending to the dataframes ebfore being deleted by teh loop

Answer (score 0):

Had to bump it outside of the inner loop and also make sure it was writing to the dictionary.. `        try:
for x in range(num_samples):
test_dict[x] , ctrl_dict[x] = train_test_split(data, test_size = 1-patchPct , stratify=data[['sales_per_store_rank', 'store_cnt_rank']])

```
    except:
        for x in range(num_samples):
            test_dict[x] , ctrl_dict[x] = train_test_split(data, test_size = 1-patchPct , stratify=data[['sales_per_store_rank', 'store_cnt_rank']])
    
    for key in test_dict.keys():
        test_dict[key] = test_dict[key].append(patchdataincl)`
```